# 12V to 5V buck converter 3A PCB

Tags: pcb, layout

I am creating my first 12V to 5V buck converter with the TI TPS56339. I've heard that the PCB layout is critical and before I send the PCB to production I wanted to get it reviewd. I tried my best to follow the guidelines for the component layout.
Could you please review my layout?

[image: Schematic]
[image: PCB Layout]

Thanks

---

Thanks for your answers. Based on your feedback I created another design. Unfortunately it is not possible to change the thermals on individual pads in Eagle. Is the design better now?

[image: PCB2]

---

Here is my 3rd design. I switched to the LMR23630 due to better part availability. I tried to follow the design guidelines in the data sheet. The output capacitor is a little far away from the IC's PGND pin. Will that be a problem?

[image: 3rd PCB Design]

Comment: Too many problems to go into details. Too hot, too noisy (EMI) and must use 2 oz copper , The board and inductor looks too small. for 15W.  I used to go into product when I started out too but only for 1 unit.  You need to look at the Eval kit , make a prototype and do a DVT

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4G1l.png

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I am limited in the width of the board (18.5mm), the length can still be increased. Do you think it is still possible with that width? The inductor was suggested by the TI power tool. EDIT: the PCB is mounted onto an aluminum profile, which can contribute to cooling.

Comment: SW node should **not** be a plane (left of L). So, reduce the area of SW node as much as possible. Rotate L 90 degrees CCW, this enables shortening the traces on the bottom. Enlarge the copper pour of Vin where the copper of SW has been removed.

Comment: @Sunnyskyguy what do you mean with too noisy? (I know what EMI is, i mean 'too')

Comment: unlikely to meet expectations

Comment: What expectations? Any standard? I haven't read any requirements in OP. But,be it e.g. EN55022 or CISPR 22, how do you judge it "too noisy" by only seeing the PCB and without knowledge of wiring and the enclosure/housing? Just curious.

Comment: The highest switching current-voltage/dt  E-B field noise radiates from sides of inductor like a dipole antenna.  Using microvias to rails adjacent to L sides, shunts these E fields from unintended radiation.  For C6,7,8 They use over 75 uvias on GND to reduce the ESL that reduces  ground shift noise which reduces Vfb error detection and increases BW..

Comment: increases BW, because reducing ESL inductance of vias lowers impedance effects from L/C and raises SRF from lower 1/LC  reduce a via from 1nH to 10 pH     ESL makes a big difference at 10MHz in terms of Z(f) where emissions tend to be high.

Comment: If you put the inductor on the other side of the board (which should be solid ground plane) then you can move the input/output caps so all the three critical GND pads (input/output cap and DC-DC chip) are very close together. Also you need ceramic cap on the output, not just electrolytic!

Answer (score 1):

Before you commit to a design, you need to have Design and Test Validation Specs (for DFT)
These include parameters like; Environmental stress, efficiency, output
voltage regulation, load transients, loop response, output ripple, input ripple, and start-up surge current, rise time and overshoot.  EMI V/m near & far field.

## What are your specs?

I think you made too many deviations from the recommended design.  [(Eval design not FCC-Approved)](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slvube6a/slvube6a.pdf)

```
from TI datasheet
1. VIN and GND traces should be as wide as possible to reduce trace impedance. 
      The wide areas are also of advantage from the view point of heat dissipation.
2. The input capacitor and output capacitor should be placed 
      as close to the device as possible to minimize trace impedance.
3. Provide sufficient vias for the input capacitor and output capacitor.
4. Keep the SW trace as physically short and wide as practical to minimize radiated emissions.
5. Do not allow switching current to flow under the device.
6. A separate VOUT path should be connected to the upper feedback resistor.
7. Make a Kelvin connection to the GND pin for the feedback path.
8. Voltage feedback loop should be placed away from the high-voltage 
      switching trace, and preferably has ground shield.
9. The trace of the VFB node should be as small as possible to avoid noise coupling.
10. The GND trace between the output capacitor and the GND pin
      should be as wide as possible to minimize its trace impedance.  (nH/mm)
```

- Copper heatsink area insufficient.
- lack of microvias around side of L which is an unshielded inductor pat of a large dI/dt and dV/dt, current loop of unintended radiation. (EMI)
- Critical feedback traces too long.
- Smaller inductors tend to have higher DCR
- lack of DFT test points for a diff probe

I am just "scratching at the surface" of the design differences
[image]

[image]

For more details on DC-DC PCB layout, **[read Rohm's paper.](http://rohmfs.rohm.com/en/products/databook/applinote/ic/power/switching_regulator/converter_pcb_layout_appli-e.pdf)**

> Major problems that arise from inappropriate layout may cause increase in noise superposed by output and switching signal,
>   the deterioration of regulator, and also lack of stability. Adopting an appropriate layout will suppress these problems to occur.
>
> Keep wiring of return path away from noise causing areas,
>   such as inductor and diode. 
>   [image]

Switched current loops look big in above "analogic" diagram but must be small in the physical layout. (loop antenna)

[image]

LC-diode placement matters to minimize loop area shown in the schematic.

[image]

Copper Weight matters for heat rise.
[image]

**Bottom Line** : Without Specs (read introduction again), *How will you verify that it works*?

Comment: it seems the recommended design cannot be implemented on a small PCB that I need. So I think I have to come up with another idea.

Comment: If size matters, use a MCPCB

Comment: Not the same Rja as an MCPCB

Comment: TI uses standard sized PCB's. Check for getting a roug idea the [thermal image of such an IC](https://www.richtek.com/Home/Design%20Support/Technical%20Document/AN004?ForceDevice=1&devicename=Richtekweb) The blue coloured area hardly functions as heatsink. Same applies to TI board.

Comment: I doubt the use of DFT. For prototype perhaps, but there are other ways. For production it would be enough to do an endurance test using the input and output connectors. If a sample fails, it's likely not worth the time measuring why it failed compared to the cost of making it.

Comment: Some questions:

- Is it in general possible to only use a 2 layer PCB?
- Am I right that the Vin and Vout plane must not be necessarily large but rather focus on maxing out the Gnd plane?
-  Does the feedback loop go over the Vin plane, so "before" the inductor?

Comment: 2 layer planes are harder or sometimes impossible to route compared to 4 layer planes. Especially with many signals (microprocessor) and/or components on limited space. When using 4 layers, it's easier implement one of the middle layers as an (almost) uninterrupted ground plane.

Comment: Regarding the Vin and Vout planes, their AC component is zero, so they act as (AC) ground plane as well. But do not add ground planes because "they're good". But try understanding how return currents would run in the ground plane.

Comment: DFT means adding test pads for low pF Diff Probes   to detect passive component effects for qualifying parts on RLC effects on Q and losses. (L/DCR, ESR*C) Note the Vsw path to Gnd is the shortest. TP5<>TP3

Comment: @Huisman  Having been in R&D for 10 Yrs also  Test Engineering for 30 yrs, I cannot stress enough the need to include DFT from the start of design thru to production to improve quality, yields and testability for here with passive quality variations on RLC effects. This is essentially an unintended RF transmitter and even TI does not guarantee their design will pass emissions testing.

Comment: Also if you analyze how DC-DC converters are done on a MOBO in a high layer count to reduce emissions, you can learn alot on layouts and microvia design beside the CPU using ultra low ESR Caps.

Comment: DFT means Design for Testability

Comment: Just out of curiosity: there are 12V to 5V DC/DC converters with 3A on e.g. Amazon that have way smaller PCBs than my design. They also have way less cooling surface. How are they doing that? [DC DC Buck Converter Step-Down Modul, 24V 12V 9V 5V 3V](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B01MQGMOKI/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_8KBFCbYSN1PQA)

Comment: Yes and at the bottom of the page some say" Output Current: 3A max (please enhance cooling work when it is full load); Other designs say nothing

Comment: Correct but if in my design I use a tStop under the DC/DC for exposed copper and then mount the pcb with thermal tape onto a large aluminum rail, that would be enough cooling I suppose. I updated my design and will post a 3rd layout soon. This time I tried to follow all design guidelines. Anyways, thanks for your input, that was really helpful!

Comment: How do you connect the board thermal without shorting out tracks. The thermal resistance depends on area of contact surface.

Comment: Well either I only expose the ground planes and then put the whole aluminum rail on ground or I'll just use a thermal pad/tape, which is electrical isolating. Of course for the later option I'll add a thermal resistance but I believe it will still be enough cooling. Also I do not have 3A continuous, this is only expected peak current. My continuous current will be around 1A.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few things:

All your ground current at the output is going through that one via.

The cuts in the top gnd pour at CIN and CINX are bottle necking it badly. There are some ways around through the vias but they're all kind of circuitous. In general you want your ground stitched together much better than this.

CIN AND CINX are also cutting up the VIN POUR badly, you need to fix that. Make sure there's a nice fat pathway for current to flow.

The pour clearance on your output thermals looks a bit small. If solder bridges onto that it could cause soldering issues. Same goes for L

I would make the feedback path shorter.

I would make the thermals on pins 2 and 3 of the switching regulator less aggressive, you can make the traces the full pin width no problem.

There's more of the same issues elsewhere but you get the idea. Check your current loops carefully, and mind those thermal cut outs.